# Speeding up boost::iterator_facade dereference

Tags: c++, performance, boost, iterator

I am using iterator_facade to provide iterator support for a class. However, because the iterator_facade::dereference returns by reference, and it is an object with a non-trivial copy-const that is being returned, my performance is suffering upon every dereference (as profiled with VTune) as a result of constantly performing these copies. Is there a way around this?

```
class time_series::iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<
                         time_series::iterator,
                         time_series::variable_vec,
                         boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag,
                         timestep> //<--- dereference type
{
public:
    iterator();
    iterator(const iterator& src);
    ~iterator();
    iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs);
private:
     //the following satisfies the reqs for a boost::facade bidirectional iterator
     friend class boost::iterator_core_access;
     friend class time_series;

     const timestep& dereference() const;
     bool equal(iterator const& other) const;
     void increment();
     void decrement();
     std::ptrdiff_t distance_to(iterator const& other) const;

     //iterators for the current step
     timestep _currentStep;// <--returned on dereference, is non-trivial to copy.
};
```

edit:
as per comment

```
const timestep& time_series::iterator::dereference() const
{
    return _currentStep;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `dereference()`, `increment()` and `decrement()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified `timestep` instead of `timestep&` as `Reference` template parameter, that's why it's constantly making copies. Change it to `timestep&` or remove at all.

Also for some reason you store `_currentStep` in the iterator by value, thus probably making copies every time you increment or decrement.

Read the [Boost tutorial on iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#the-problem) for a reference how to implement facade properly.

Comment: Ah, alright. So, dumb question: if I make that first change, how do I access a method in the object returned by the dereference? That is, timestep::my_method()?

Comment: @Chris As in `it->my_method()` (which is equivalent to `(*it).my_method()`, mind the brackets)?

Comment: @LucDanton yea...that's what I thought. In this example, _currentStep is a wrapper around a tbb::concurrent_hasmap that holds iterators into tbb::concurrent_vector s. Essentially it steps forward the iterators in lockstep. When I do itr->my_method() I get a compiler error that 'my_method' is not a member of tbb::concurrent_vector. Which seems...bizarre.

Comment: ah I'm an idiot, I had that as the return of my iterator. In fact, I'm stunned this ever worked! Everything is much much faster, thanks!